# Importer failed to import posts as format "day and name"

Tags: permalinks, import, export

I had a blog exposing posts as "day and name". After exporting that blog and importing it on a new installation of WordPress I can't see the posts in that format, only in the default one: http://blog.xxxxx.com/main/?p=123

Also moving to previous pages (http://blog.xxxxx.com/main/page/2/) does not work.

Is this a known issue with a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WordPress .xml import file only contains post data and not any site settings, such as permalinks. It seems to me that this is only an issue of setting the permalinks the same way of your old site.

- Settings -> Permalinks (`/wp-admin/options-permalink.php`)
- select `Day and name`
- save changes

If WordPress can't update the .htaccess file, follow this instructions:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Automatically_updating_.htaccess

[update]

In case it is a server problem:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Permalinks_without_mod_rewrite

http://wpengineer.com/2318/pretty-permalinks-without-mod_rewrite/

Comment: This is what I did without success. I didn't receive a message regarding .htaccess file

Comment: Sorry then, I haven't understood from your question that you did refresh the permalinks. Is the new installation in the same server as the old? It can be a mod_rewrite problem. Check the update in my answer. @mrwweb, thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: The issue was related to AWS EC2 instances not having enabled the RewriteEngine on a specific virtual domain. Marking it as answered since it was related to .htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a hit to this plugin : https://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-editor/

It helps me to edit and get my permalink back when i move from one server to another.

hope it helps.